# "small room" vs. "little room" / "big room" vs. "large room"

Tags: differences

I never had problems with *small* and *little* before.

However, I only had known about *a small room* before I saw the word *a little room* in a textbook (Family and Friends by Naomi Simmons). Is it the same?

Also, as I always use *big*, I'm not so sure about *large*. *Big room* and *large room* were the same to me. Is it right?

Comment: Could you provide some more contexts like adding the example sentences that you're thinking of?

Comment: Are you asking if *small* and *little* are the same?

Comment: ...If so, there are previous questions on the subject. The words are (as adjectives) synonyms, but that doesn't mean that there is always a free choice of which to use. 'She bought a pretty little cottage' sounds wonderful, while 'She bought a pretty small cottage' sounds less so (but is not ungrammatical).

Comment: Have you checked the four words in the dictionary?

Comment: The context is like: "I bought a new house. The small/little room is for my daughter." And I don't sure which word to use.
As I said, I wonder if "small room" and 'little room" is the same.

Comment: About "big" and "large", I checked the dictionary and things are clear now, thank you. "Large" is more formal than big and should be used in writing unless it is in an informal style. It is not usually used to describe people, except to avoid saying "fat".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Small refers to size. In many cases both small and little are possible. However, little is preferred in cases where we also want to express some sort of emotion. Examples could be:-

> a. Poor little thing.
>
> b. She is a pretty little woman.
>
> c. They have bought a small house in the city.
>
> d. The small hours

Large is a bit more formal and stronger word than big and there are some cases we prefer large over big or vice versa. Large also emphasizes 'big in more than one dimensions' area or volume. Some examples from the [grammarbank.com](http://www.grammarbank.com/big-large-great.html) :-

> a. We need a larger cup. (Need more volume)
>
> b. We need a bigger knife.(No volume emphasized)

Comment: But note that *"bigger cup"* and *"larger knife"* are not mistakes; they're just slightly less likely alternative ways to say the same thing.

Comment: This is the sentence in the textbook: "The bedroom is little". So you mean we can use both words for that sentence?

Comment: @Appple Yes you can use both, with slight difference in meaning.